# Is there a way to combine similar data in sheets automatically and have Tableau connect to read data

Tags: excel, database, tableau-api, spreadsheet

I have 4 Sheets sheets with similar fields. I intend to merge these sheets together to create a master file that has all information in one sheet. However, i need Tableau to connect to the final merged file so i can  create dashboards off. This works locally as i have an access program that appends the tables together and creates a new table which Tableau connects to.

The main issue is i am trying to take this process offline (to run online to locally), meaning i need a database that can;
1- Drop content of the tables, pick up the sheets from a specified folder, import them into specified tables.
2- Append new tables into master tables.

All of this should be done automatically at a scheduled time.
I tried using SQL server (SQL Agent for scheduling job import/append etc) for this requirement but i need to know if something else is out there that can serve this purpose efficiently.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the sheets have the exact fields, you should be able to use Tableau's [Union](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/union.htm) feature. This feature will allow you to do a wildcard search for sheets within a folder structure. Anytime the data is refreshed in Tableau it will reach back out to the folder and update/union what is currently there.